# Modifying Crystal Report via Visual Studio project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

When I open a Crystal Report in Visual Studio I can view options for how the fields are formatted such as the date and numbers. I'm running a crystal report in a project, is it possible to edit these settings through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the NumericFieldFormat values of the objects.
See an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225929%28v=vs.90%29.aspx